# Как создать DMG для кода на python

Tags: python

Создал небольшое приложение (десктопное) и хочу сделать для него dmg файл. Подскажите есть, что то подобное auto-py-to-exe но для IOS?
Спасибо!

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/kivy-android-ios-exe

Comment: https://likegeeks.com/kivy-tutorial/